# How to remove an blank interface type from an union in Typescript

Tags: typescript

```
type A = {}

 interface B {
  defaultText: string | null;
}

 interface C {
  json: any;
}

 interface D {
  rowsCollection: {item:string[]};
}

 type Union =
  | A
  | B
  | C
  | D;
```

The question here is how to remove the `A` from `Union`?

It is easy for removing the other type like`type UnionWithoutB = Exclude<Union, B>`, the `UnionWithoutB` here will be `A|C|D`

but `type UnionWithoutA = Exclude<Union, A>` will give you `never`.

**My question is:**
**How to remove the blank interface type `A` here from the union type `Union` in Typescript?**

These are types generated from GraphQL schema, and we do not have the control over them. Please solve without changing the current types but only adding new.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick

```js
type RemoveBlankInterfaceFromUnion<T> = 
  T extends infer U 
    ? {} extends U 
      ? never 
      : U
    : never
;
```

It works by using [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) to break up the union and omit anything that the type `{}` is assignable to.

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEDECcHsFtQI4FcCmBnALgS2gOwFD4YCeADiqAIKgC8oA3gL6Gha4YqQBmAhgMYUAQg3yhQAExS8kAGwwAVFAA8MALlCZIbAOagAPqFyyZAbnzNRbDt34UAwiLEArNHnU9cxMxdbtOvAVAAEUdQGAB3NDtoGRkUPmw3BiwOWFVNHQBtAF1GbxYSclAAVVwcXFpRfSoqg0Fa0DsGoLN8ECpcNHDOQkKKACUUWGgANxRBGQ8AawBJPxsBKDhS8oAeeQA+WlAq+VBlDlxxNF8uThKdsTEAfgZGfZUUI5Piy6ubwxQxyDf39WKqmJ1Lgvj1Wvg4hhQCMAIzqJjbBE8E4eLyEdoAAQwaAAtMpyAk8ZAYD8NAALaCycT7YnQH44nH7WCkEi+awBCi4aCgGR4bTnHigUg8SBQ6BcUAYMkUJBlPAQlBQkYAJnUg2GYwm0zm7NsS1gKzwq0NuC2dFhJiAA)

---

The reason that `Exclude<Union, {}>` gives `never` is because all object types in Typescript are assignable to `{}` for the same reason that `{ apple: number; banana: string }` is assignable to `{ apple: number }`.